# Split the touch screen into 4 quadrants?

Tags: java, android, screen, theory

I'm creating a simple game on android where you touch a certain part of the screen when told to do so.  My main question is it possible to just split the screen into 4 quadrants and recognize when the quadrants were touched? Or would it be easier just to have 4 large buttons where I want the quadrants to be?  I'm kind of new to android programming (only like 2 1/2 weeks in) but I've learned quite a bit in those 2 1/2 weeks.

If you guys feel it would simply be easier if I just used 4 big buttons then let me know.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You get x, y coordinates for your touch event and you can easily get the width and height of the View, so you could just logically split into quadrants yourself. That said, if you don't have to do any custom drawing or UI, and all you need is four areas to press, there's nothing wrong with using four buttons.

Comment: I'll probably use the four buttons then.  The method for them would just be adding to a string anyway...thank you.  I do have to do custom drawing but I can just use images for the buttons so it should work out

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the answer you are looking for ...have you looked at [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html)

Answer (score 0):

Almost 10 years later, this is what I did in Xamarin.Android in a GestureListener

```
public class GestureListener : Java.Lang.Object, IOnTouchListener
 {
     public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
        var xCenter = v.MeasuredWidth / 2;
        var yCenter = v.MeasuredHeight / 2;

        if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
        {
            float xTouch = 0;
            float yTouch = 0;

            xTouch = (e.GetX() - xCenter);
            yTouch = yCenter - e.GetY();

            Console.WriteLine("x: " + xTouch + " y: " + yTouch);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```